# Rails simpleform pre data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

How do I make a simple form association have pre data when editing?

My form:

```
<h1>Editing kategori</h1>
<%= simple_form_for(@konkurrancer, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @konkurrancer.id }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.association :kategoris  %>
    <%= f.button :submit, :value => 'Edit konkurrence' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to do something like this in your **controller**:

```
def edit
  @konkurrancer = Konkurrancer.new(:title => "hello wurld", :description => "blah blah blah", :nuclear_level => 10)
end
```

Then your form should automatically populate these values as "pre data".

Answer (score 1):

You almost did it:

```
<%= f.button :submit, :value => 'Edit konkurrence', :data_pre => "whatever here" %>
```

Comment: I thought you were wiling to add values to your process into you dom with js